# qt c++ scrollBar в начало списка

Tags: c++, qt, прокрутка

Всем привет. Есть длинный список в tableWidget. При обновлении списка horizontalScrollBar не сбрасывается вначало списка, а остается в той позиции где он был, как его сбросить? например по кнопке Ок.

Comment: задать на кнопку Ок действие ui->horizontalScrollBar ->setValue(0)

Comment: ui->tableWidget->horizontalScrollBar() дальше ничего нет.

Comment: а может тогда кусок кода покажите???

Comment: как вариант можно еще конектом 'connect(table1->horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), table2->horizontalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int)));'

Comment: Методы отобразились только после того как подключил QScrollBar. Парился ток с этим. Думал для QTableWidget они автоматом определяются, без включения инклюда.

Comment: а ну все, проблему пофиксили??

Comment: да, спасибо. Мой косяк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

задать на кнопку Ок действие `ui->horizontalScrollBar ->setValue(0)` и подключить `#include <QScrollBar>`

Answer (score 0):

Вот более гибкий способ. В начало
ui->tableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(ui->tableWidget->verticalScrollBar->minimum()); Для того чтобы был в конце списка в конце, вместо метода minimum поставить метод maximum.